# Button text centered in Windows but not in Linux/android CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, materialize

I'm working on a web page and I have a curious problem with the vertical alignment of the text of the button. I'm using Materialize framework and a custom font, but as we can see in the picture, in windows is perfectly aligned, but not in linux and Android:

Windows capture:

[image: Windows capture]

Linux capture:

[image: Linux capture]

Anyone has an idea of how to fix this? I tried adding a padding, but with that it works fine in linux and bad in windows. Also I set line-height to 1, vertical-align center, but nothing works.

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**

Code for the button:

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  font-family: 'X';
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

.green {
  background-color: #00cd78 !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green submit-btn right">login</button>
```

The rest is the default style of Materialize for those classes.

Comment: Would you be able to show your code for this button please?

Comment: @billy.farroll done, but I didn't include the materialize code, as it is quite extense, but if you need it, I can put it.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your `.btn` class CSS with-

```
.btn {
   width: 100px;
   font-family: 'X';
   font-size: 0.85em;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
```

Comment: the `.right` class is just for floating right: `.right {
    float: right !important;
}`